# How to open a file on my Sharepoint Site with VBA if I dont have internet connection?

Tags: vba, excel, sharepoint

I have a macro that opens a file on a Sharepoint Site, uses that file to generate a new file to be saved into the same Sharepoint Site. If I am currently connected to the Internet, the macro runs perfectly fine. When I am disconected from the internet the macro is unable to open the file, even if I am referencing a path to my local Drive. For example

```
Set wdApp = New Word.Application
'make word Visible'
wdApp.Visible = True
wdApp.Activate
'open File'
wdApp.Documents.Open (D:\mySharepointSite\file.dotx")
```

Comment: Assuming you retyped your code in your question... You're missing the opening quote in the `wdApp.Documents.Open` line. Should be `("D:\...` not `(D:\...`

Comment: When you say you don't have an Internet connection, are you talking about the whole world wide web, your corporate intr_a_net, or the corporate LAN?

Comment: Hah, you can’t connect to your share point site without internet! The “local” drive you have is just a mapped network driver to the location on the internet, so it’s not truly local

Answer (score 0):

Everything on Sharepoint is stored in "The Cloud" which is (roughly) a fancy name for "The Internet". If you aren't connected to the internet you can't connect to sharepoint.